# Explanation of the blood on Marta Cabrera's shoe

Tags: plot-explanation, knives-out

In *Knives Out*, it is absolutely not clear where the drop of blood on Marta Cabrera's shoe come from?

Answer (score 21):

Harlan slits his throat so the blood would spurt out everywhere in front of him. He did this so the police could tell that no one was in front of him as the blood patterns would show someone was there. Marta went back into the room just as he was about to cut his throat, she  was far away so avoided the majority of blood but a small droplet managed to make it onto her shoe as she was standing in the doorway.